# Making the same change to multiple dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I have multiple dataframes, for example `df_example01`, `df_example02`, `df_example03`, and `df_example04`

I need to make changes to 01 and 02, using 03 and 04 as the source.

for example:

```
df_example01 = df_example03['aaa','bbb','ccc']
df_example02 = df_example04['aaa','bbb','ccc']
```

With only 4 example dfs, this is easily done by hand.

With more than 4, is there a simple way to loop this? Like via a dictionary or a for loop?

Comment: Can you provide some mock data that we can easily start with

Comment: What is the relation between dfs 01 and 03, or 02 and 04? With more dataframes, how would they relate?

Comment: df_01 and df_02 are new dataframes based off a subset of the data in df_03 and df_04 respectively.

there was an error in my original question. originally, i had df_02 = df_04['111','222','333']. this was incorrect. column names in df03 and df04 would always be the same, which is why i think there should be an easy way to loop this. ive updated the question accordingly.

Comment: now both df01 and df02 are subsets of df03 and df04 with the same column names, just not sure how to automate/loop this

Comment: please explain with few data set.

Comment: for example:

df_Prim_Output_Excel = df_Prim_Bonus_Groups[["ID", "Name",  "Group", "Sub_Total", "Bonus", "Total Payout"]]

df_Second_Output_Excel = df_Second_Bonus_Groups[["ID", "Name",  "Group", "Sub_Total", "Bonus", "Total Payout"]]

df_Third_Output_Excel = df_Third_Bonus_Groups[["ID", "Name",  "Group", "Sub_Total", "Bonus", "Total Payout"]]

df_Fourth_Output_Excel = df_Fourth_Bonus_Groups[["ID", "Name",  "Group", "Sub_Total", "Bonus", "Total Payout"]]

Answer (score 0):

Use a list of dataframes, then iterate though the list.  You may want to use a separate function too.

```
row1list = ['1.2.3 4']
row2list = ['1.4.5 6']
row3list = ['2.7.8 9']
df1 = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list, row3list], columns=['col'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list, row3list], columns=['col'])

df_list = [df1, df2]
for df in df_list:
    df['col'] += ' change'

print(df1)
#               col
# 0  1.2.3 4 change
# 1  1.4.5 6 change
# 2  2.7.8 9 change
```